# Mysql doesn't run on wamp, icon still orange

Tags: mysql, windows-10, wamp

I was looking for a solution for the last 3hours around the internet and I can't get anything, the wamp icon is orange, 2 of 3 services running..  and I can't log in to my database from http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ , I tried to change the ports and all the solutions that I could find on youtube, but it didn't work, please help me.

EDIT : it seems that there is a problem with Mysql port, when I test it they say :

***** Test which uses port 3306 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 3306 =====

Port 3306 is not found associated with TCP protocol
Port 3306 is not found associated with TCP protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by uninstalling WAMP using iobit and clean the registry using Ccleaner, and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

@Aymane HR if i tell you an alternative to wamp. which never gets down and starts stops within seconds. Also, it doesn't take too much ram as wamp does. Its name UwAMP. Downlaod it because it takes only 135mb of your laps ram however wamp will take 1gb to 2gb. Hope you don't mind because i am answering the question out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to install over an older version or non empty wamp folder. Uninstalling and reinstalling on another path could solve your problem.

Are you executing the Wamp manager as Administrator?